# AJAX request to XML in GZIP/ZIP format - How do I decompress data in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to fetch XML data but I'm unable to use it as I don't know how to decompress the data. I have two options I can either use GZIP or a ZIP file from the data provider.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url:"https://example.xml.gz",
        crossDomain: true,
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data); 
                 }});
});
```

I can see the compressed code of the gzipped file in my console returned from the AJAX call but don't know how to decompress it so I can use it in my project.

Could someone show me how to decompress a ZIP or GZIP file following an AJAX request.

---

I have tried the following solution from stackoverflow [Is there a way to parse a zipped XML file with JQuery on the fly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9462506/is-there-a-way-to-parse-a-zipped-xml-file-with-jquery-on-the-fly/9462563#9462563)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$.ajax({
    url:"https://example.xml.gz",
    beforeSend: function (jqXHR) {
        jqXHR.setRequestHeader('Accept-Encoding', 'gzip');
    },
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data); 
             }});
});
```

This code returns an error in the console...

> Attempt to set a forbidden header was denied: Accept-Encoding

---

I have also tried to set `dataType:` to `"xml"` but when I do this instead of seeing the compressed xml data in the console I see.

> XML Parsing Error: not well-formed Location: http://192.168.0.11:3000/ Line Number 1, Column 1:

Comment: Have you not considered finding a javascript library that can handle .GZ files? The alternative of course, is to implement the DEFLATE algorithm as described by Mark Adddler, yourself. (find a library!)

Comment: I tried pako but it didn't work, could you recommend a library to use?